# Kibana Visualization not showing created fields in Aggregation -> Terms -> Fields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to create a visualization in kibana which shows the average of different data. I have created the fields which shows in logs and also I did Management -> Index pattern -> Refresh.
Now when I try to create a graph in visualize -> e.x (bar chart) -> Aggregate -> Terms -> fields does not shows required fields. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: If this is an text field, make sure changing the mapping to keyword or at least create an keyword  subfield

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your issue well, you need an average of a particular field while isolating them in particular categories?

I have the following data in the index `kibana-terms`.

```
{
"category": "drama",
"rating": 5
},
{
"category": "romance",
"rating": 5
},
{
"category": "action",
"rating": 1
},
{
"category": "drama",
"rating": 10
},
{
"category": "drama",
"rating": 8
}
```

Note: I am still considering category as a text field however, it should have been a `keyword` data type.

I created a vertical barchart as follows:

[image]

I adjusted the filters as follows:

[image]

The `aggregation` can be selected from the drop menu itself. It is by default `count`.

The x-axis is where the isolation part takes place, where the `Terms aggregation` is being used on the `category` field.

Let me know if you need help, I will be glad to help you out.